# Linear Algebra nullSpace and multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If you have a $m \times n$ matrix $A$, and an $n \times p$ matrix $B$ and $AB=0$. Is the $dim (null  A) = p$? No clue how to start this.

Comment: What if $B=\textbf{0}$?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem to be true.

$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-1 \\
1 \\
0 \end{array} \right) =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 
 \end{array} \right) $ but $\operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{ker}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0
 \end{array} \right)\right) = 2$.

If you add another hypothesis, $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}B)=0$ you can say that $\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{ker}A)$ is **at least** $p$.